# How to understand the process of Kerberos (over Hadoop)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I have deployed Kerberos in hadoop cluster. According to the theory, the KDC will verify you are the one as you clared, according to the private key.

However, using that system confused me. For example, if you need access to the HDFS, what you need to do is just to input `"kinit hdfs@MY.REALM"` and the password from a client. Then you will get ticket and manipulate the HDFS as the superuser "hdfs".

Does this the real process of kerberos? If the user are only verified by password, why don't we directly build a list inside the server and require the user to input its `username/password`? Where is the private key mentioned in the theory? Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: The password *is* the private key. It can be as long and complex as you want, and it can be stored in a "keytab" file -- *using cryptographic hashing* -- so that scheduled jobs and services can authenticate (and re-authenticate) automatically. Just make sure to restrict access to that "keytab" file at filesystem level  :-/

Comment: The whole point of Kerberos is to build a **global** authorization system, with robust network security. On that basis you can build a reasonable level of **trust** between **remote systems**.

Comment: BTW your phrasing is ambiguous: `kinit hdfs@MY.REALM` requires the password for the **hdfs** privileged account. Just like `su - root` requires the password for root.

Comment: Thx a lot for your patient explaination @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: But one more question my friend....  If the password is the private key used to verify the user,  why don't we directly add a page that requires username and password on the server? It looks simpler than setting up a KDC....  @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: Indeed, Kerberos is not very useful if you access a *single* server. On the other hand, if you want to be able to login on any server/desktop in your corporation, and access any disk share or app server in any of your data centers worldwide, then you deploy Active Directory or a similar directory; and guess what's underneath? Yes, indeed, Kerberos. If you want to enable security on a distributed system such as Hadoop or Kafka, what protocol do you enable? Kerberos.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your explaination...but I am so sorry to bother you again my friend... I just came up with a question regarding Kerberos: I enabled Kerberos protocol on my cluster, and any client cannot visit HDFS or other serves like spark kafka hbase... without ticket from KDC.   My question is...can I implement further authorization? For example, the client with ticket A can only visit HDFS HBASE, but cannot access kafka and spark...    Can this be done by Kerberos? If not, would you mind to give some advice? Thank you very much...

Comment: Kerberos manages *authentication*. For *authorization* you use ACLs (access control lists) based on user names / group names. Sometimes there is also the concept of Role to make authorization easier. It all depends on which component you are using.